# Удалить одинаковые строки из массива по первым значениям, с сохранением и суммированием одного значения

Tags: python, массивы, pandas, dataframe

я хочу удалить дубликаты из массива по первым четырем значениям, с сохранением последнего значения, путем суммирования с оставшимся уникальным значением. Т.е. имеется множество строк такого вида:

```
1  3  1  2  5040
6  3  2  1  5040
1  3  1  2  320
8  3  3  0  1680
```

Мне нужно удалить все строки с повторениями первых четырех чисел, в данном случае это `1 3 1 2`, и оставить только одну, но с изменением пятого значения на значения из той же колонки у удаленных строк, т.е. в итоге должно получится такое:

```
1  3  1  2  5360
6  3  2  1  5040
8  3  3  0  1680
```

У меня получилось удалить дубликаты по первым четырем значениям таким образом(pandas):

```
datalst = pd.DataFrame(smlst3, columns = ["1","2","3","4","all"])
datalst = datalst.drop_duplicates(["1","2","3","4"],keep='first')
```

Но не понимаю как можно сохранить значения из пятой колонки в уникальную строку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто группируем фрейм по всем столбцам кроме столбца `all`
 и суммируем:

```
In [63]: res = df.groupby(df.columns.drop('all').tolist(), as_index=False).sum()

In [64]: res
Out[64]:
   1  2  3  4   all
0  1  3  1  2  5360
1  6  3  2  1  5040
2  8  3  3  0  1680
```